# O que é o Substitution Model em Scala - Modelo de Substituição

Tags: programação-funcional, scala, play-framework

**Substitution Model - Modelo de Substituição**

Qual é o conceito por traz?

Como ele Funciona? No que ele afeta a maneira como programamos em Scala

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aai5f5RBq98

Answer (score 0):

Eu estou supondo que você está se referindo diretamente ao que Martin discute no livro ou no curso do Coursera. De qualquer forma a resposta não deve afetar o contexto da pergunta tanto assim.

A idéia principal é que a construção de expressões seja feita a partir de outras expressões que representem algum valor independente de qualquer contexto externo, exatamente como se faz na matemática.

Por exemplo. Na expressão `4 + RaizQuadrada(25)`, podemos substituir por `4 + 5` sem nenhum prejuizo para o valor final. Também podemos substituir por `RaizQuadrada(16) + RaizQuadrada(25)`. A função `RaizQuadrada` não depende de nenhum elemento externo. Podemos dizer que `5 == RaizQuadrada(25)` sem nos preocupar com qualquer estado/variável global.

Isso significa que ao construir nossas funções com esse princípio em mente, uma função deve retornar apenas um valor que só depende dos argumentos passados a ela. E que essa função pode ser referenciada inúmeras vezes sem que altere o resultado ou qualquer estado externo a ela.

Isso afeta na prática a maneira de programar (em scala), uma vez que você tem a garantia que pode combinar funções da maneira que quiser sem se preocupar com a ordem em que elas vão ser chamadas, visto que não existe um estado global afetado pela execução delas. Você pode testar essas funções independentemente. Você pode modularizar o seu código mais facilmente, visto que agora as funções só dependem dos argumentos.